# How can I lock the Kindle Fire's app-store to require a pin number for purchases?

Tags: kindle

*I'm sure this is a duplicate, but I can't find an answer on SuperUser with these words and it seems useful to at least provide a redirect.*

On the Amazon Kindle Fire, how can I require that a pin number be entered for *every* purchase, whether it is in their appstore or in one of their games?  If there isn't a global way to do this, is there a way to secure all methods of purchasing with a pin?

Comment: I'm afraid general tablet questions are outside the scope of [su], according to the [faq]. I don't think there's a SE site for which tablet questions fall within the scope of at all currently. :( You might try [chat], or look at [area51.se] to see if there's a site trying to get off the ground for which your question would help.

Comment: How does one petition to update the scope of a site?  Will Windows 8 fall under this scope too?

Comment: Actually as things are now, tablet questions are [on topic](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5045/please-vote-on-proposed-changes-to-our-policy-on-tablet-computers), mainly cause of windows 8 RT.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Ah, so that meta post seems to have settled on a conclusion. Cool to know :) My apologies for the misinformation, Ross!

Comment: No worries.  It was a long-shot retort anyway :-P  It just sucks when your question barely falls out of the scope of a stack-exchange site and there are no alternatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current Kindle Fire firmware supports parental controls, which when enabled requires a password to make any purchase. It is accessed from the `Settings` menu (gear icon at the top of the screen) then select `More` then `Parental Controls`. This function was added to Kindle Fire in an update earlier this year.

Comment: Very nice.  I was going to begin the process of rooting and installing the google app store today or tomorrow due to the number of purchases my kids keep making.  Thanks gordoco!